# Using zip in a chain

Tags: underscore.js

Is it possible to chain `zip` to transpose an array of arrays?

```
var data = _(raw)
  .map(function(d) { return d.events; })
  .zip()  // how do I do this step?
  .map(function(d) { 
    return {
      time: d[0].time,
      total: _.reduce(d, function(total, event) { return total += event.amount; })
    };
  });
```

[The docs](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) show how to transpose an array, but not as part of a chain:

```
_.zip.apply(_, arrayOfRowsOfData);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a mixin and call that within your chain:

```
_.mixin( { zipMeUp: function(arrays){
    return _.zip.apply(_, arrays);
}});

var result = _.chain(data)
    .zipMeUp()
    .value();
```

Comment: This worked great, didn't know about `.mixin`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna try `unzip` instead in chain where the input is a list of lists. We almost ended up writing a mixin but then read https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/965.

```
JSON.stringify(_([['john', 'jill'], [20, 40]]).zip().value())
=> "[[["john","jill"]],[[20,40]]]"
JSON.stringify(_([['john', 'jill'], [20, 40]]).unzip().value())
=> "[["john",20],["jill",40]]"
```